# "Hay" en futuro simple

Tags: futuro

No sé como utilizar **hay** en futuro simple. 
Por ejemplo: "Sobre la mesa hay un pastel". Si convertimos esta oración en futuro, tendremos: "Sobre la mesa habrá un pastel". Aquí todo está claro.

Pero si cambiamos oración anterior de siguiente manera: "Sobre la mesa hay unos pasteles". ¿Cómo será correcto?

1. Sobre la mesa habrá unos pasteles
2. Sobre la mesa habrán unos pasteles

Lo que intento preguntar es que hay que conjugar verbo **haber** cuando éste tiene función de **hay** en todos tiempos aparte del presente.

Comment: Como yo lo entiendo lo correcto es la opción (1) (habrá).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

La forma correcta es *habrá*. En esta clase de oración el verbo *haber* es impersonal y no concuerda con la frase nominal.

Del [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=haber), entrada **haber** (énfasis mío):

> Además de su empleo como auxiliar, el otro uso
>   fundamental de *haber* es denotar la presencia o existencia de lo
>   designado por el sustantivo que lo acompaña y que va normalmente
>   pospuesto al verbo: *Hay alguien esperándote*; *Había un taxi en la
>   puerta*; *Mañana no habrá función*; *Hubo un serio problema*. Como se ve en
>   el primer ejemplo, en este uso, la tercera persona del singular del
>   presente de indicativo adopta la forma especial *hay*. Esta construcción
>   es heredera de la existente en latín tardío «*habere* (siempre en
>   tercera persona del singular) + nombre singular o plural en
>   acusativo». **Así pues, etimológicamente, esta construcción carece de
>   sujeto; es, por tanto, impersonal y, en consecuencia, el sustantivo
>   pospuesto desempeña la función de complemento directo.**  (...)
>   **Puesto que el sustantivo que aparece en
>   estas construcciones es el complemento directo, el hecho de que dicho
>   sustantivo sea plural no supone que el verbo haya de ir también en
>   plural, ya que la concordancia con el verbo la determina el sujeto, no
>   el complemento directo.** Por consiguiente, en estos casos, lo más
>   apropiado es que el verbo permanezca en singular, y así sucede en el
>   uso culto mayoritario, especialmente en la lengua escrita, tanto en
>   España como en América: *«Había muchos libros en aquella casa»* (Ocampo
>   Cornelia [Arg. 1988]); *«Había unos muchachos correteando»* (VLlosa Tía
>   [Perú 1977]); *«Hubo varios heridos graves»* (Valladares Esperanza [Cuba
>   1985]); *«Habrá muchos muertos»* (Chao Altos [Méx. 1991]).

En el uso habitual sólo encontrarás *habrán* (en plural) cuando el verbo sea un auxiliar en un tiempo compuesto, como por ejemplo: *Para cuando lleguemos ya habrán terminado.*

Resumiendo, entonces, a *hay* en el presente le corresponde *hubo* en el pretérito indefinido, *había* en el pretérito imperfecto, *habrá* en el futuro simple, *habría* en el potencial, *haya* en el presente del subjuntivo, *hubiese* o *hubiera* en el pretérito del subjuntivo, etc., todos ellos en su forma impersonal, que es idéntica al singular.